# What is an NTAP when referenced in a NOTAM?

Tags: notam

When reviewing notices to airmen (NOTAMs) for the KDNL airport today (08 April, 2016) there's a particular NOTAM that references an NTAP with a number. What's an NTAP? How does one go about looking one up?

```
!DNL 03/008 KDNL SVC SPECIAL EVENT MASTER'S GOLF TOURNAMENT SEE NTAP 1604031100-1604112359
```

Comment: Not sure if thats the NTAP number, its formatted as a time... [20]16 04 03 11:00 to [20]16 04 11 23:59, basically April 3, 2016 at 11 until April 11, 2016 at 23:59

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Notice to Airmen Publication](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/notices/) is an FAA publication, currently available in PDF or print form, published every 28 days. The NTAP contains airway, airport, facility, procedural, general, and international NOTAMs. As voretaq7 notes, this includes long term NOTAMs that a flight service brief won't include if you don't ask. There is also a section with graphic notices, including general notices, special operations, airport and facility notices, and major sporting and entertainment events.

That last section is the one relevant for the NOTAM listed above. This lists information and procedures for any airports affected by special events, which is nice to have in one place rather than looking up long and complicated NOTAMs for each airport. For example, the Masters Golf Tournament referenced in the NOTAM above has a section in the NTAP, affecting airports AGS, AIK, DNL, and HQU. The information includes preferred IFR arrival routings, potential for holds and VFR arrival delays, departure procedures, preferred IFR departure routes, IFR overflights, and VFR arrivals/departures to/from DNL. There is also a special schedule for the tower at AGS, and a temporary tower at DNL.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the NTAP (also sometimes referred to as "the printed NOTAMs") also includes long-standing NOTAMs that won't be read to you by a flight service briefer: You need to ask for them specifically, or review the NTAP yourself.

Answer (score 3):

NTAP is the Notice to Airmen Publication. It is published every 28 days. The electronic version can be found in the [faa site](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/notices/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply enough, it is the "Notices to Airmen publication", which has the full description of the NOTAM.